# Weird Sudoku validation bug

Tags: python, algorithm, copy, sudoku

I'm currently trying to program a recursive sudoku solving algorithm in Python. I made a class for Sudokus which contains some methods to help me manipulate the sudoku grid.

Here is my code :

```
class Sudoku:
    def __init__(self, input, tokens = None):
        self.data = {}
        if tokens is None:
            self.tokens = list(range(1, 10))
        else:
            self.tokens = tokens

        assert len(self.tokens) == 9
        if type(input) == dict:
            self.data = input
        else:
            for i, cell in enumerate(input):
                if cell in self.tokens:
                    self.data[i % 9, i // 9] = cell

    def __repr__(self):
        string = ''
        canvas = [['.'] * 9 for line in range(9)]
        for (col, row), cell in self.data.items():
            canvas[row][col] = str(cell)
        for y, row in enumerate(canvas):
            if not y % 3:
                string += "+-------+-------+-------+\n"
            string += '| {} | {} | {} |\n'.format(' '.join(row[:3]), ' '.join(row[3:6]), ' '.join(row[6:]))
        string += "+-------+-------+-------+"
        return string

    @classmethod
    def sq_coords(cls, cell_x, cell_y):
        #returns all coordinates of cells in the same square as the one in (cell_x, cell_y)
        start_x, start_y = cell_x // 3 * 3, cell_y // 3 * 3
        for dx in range(3):
            for dy in range(3):
                yield (start_x +dx, start_y + dy)

    def copy(self):
        return Sudoku(self.data)

    def clues(self, cell_x, cell_y):
        assert not self.data.get((cell_x, cell_y))
        allowed = set(self.tokens)
        #Remove all numbers on the same row, column and square as the cell
        for row in range(9):
            allowed.discard(self.data.get((cell_x, row)))
        for col in range(9):
            allowed.discard(self.data.get((col, cell_y)))
        for coords in self.sq_coords(cell_x, cell_y):
            allowed.discard(self.data.get(coords))
        return allowed

    def get_all_clues(self):
        clues = {}
        for row in range(9):
                for col in range(9):
                    if not self.data.get((col, row)):
                        clues[col, row] = self.clues(col, row)
        return clues

    def fill_singles(self):
        still_going = True
        did_something = False
        while still_going:
            still_going = False
            for (col, row), clues in self.get_all_clues().items():
                if len(clues) == 1:
                    still_going = True
                    did_something = True
                    self.data[col, row] = clues.pop()
        return did_something

    def place_finding(self):
        still_going = True
        did_something = False
        while still_going:
            still_going = False
            for token in self.tokens:
                for group in self.get_groups():
                    available_spots = [coords for coords, cell in group.items() if cell == None and token in self.clues(*coords)]
                    if len(available_spots) == 1:
                        self.data[available_spots.pop()] = token
                        still_going = True
                        did_something = True
        return did_something

    def fill_obvious(self):
        still_going = True
        while still_going:
            a = self.fill_singles()
            b = self.place_finding()
            still_going = a or b

    def get_groups(self):
        for y in range(9):
            yield {(x, y) : self.data.get((x, y)) for x in range(9)}
        for x in range(9):
            yield {(x, y) : self.data.get((x, y)) for y in range(9)}
        for n in range(9):
            start_x, start_y = n % 3 * 3, n // 3 * 3
            yield {(x, y) : self.data.get((x, y)) for x, y in self.sq_coords(start_x, start_y)}

    def is_valid(self):
        for group in self.get_groups():
            if any([list(group.values()).count(token) > 1 for token in self.tokens]):
                return False
        return True

    def is_solved(self):
        return self.is_valid() and len(self.data) == 9 * 9

def solve(sudoku):
        def loop(su):
            if su.is_solved():
                print(su)
            elif su.is_valid():
                su.fill_obvious()
                print(su)
                for coords, available_tokens in sorted(su.get_all_clues().items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[1])):
                    for token in available_tokens:
                        new_su = su.copy()
                        new_su.data[coords] = token
                        loop(new_su)
        loop(sudoku)

with open('input.txt') as f:
    numbers = ''
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 9:
            break
        numbers += line.rstrip().ljust(9)

s = Sudoku(numbers, tokens='123456789')

print(s)
solve(s)
print(s)
```

Sorry if this seems messy but I'd rather give you everything I have than only some data that may or may not contain the problem.

As you can see, the first thing it does is filling the Sudoku with only 100% sure numbers using the methods fill_singles (fills every cell that can only be filled with number x, eg the 8 other possibilities are in its row, column or block) and place_finding (checks all tokens and see if there's only one space in a group - row, column or block - where they can fit). It loops through both of those until nothing can be done.

Afterwards, it tries every possibility in spaces that have least and tries to solves the newly made grid with the same method. That's where my problem is. Currently, for debug purposes, the program prints grids it comes across whenever they're valid (no same number twice in a group). Actually that's what I'd like it to do. However it doesn't work like this; with this input :

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| . . . | . 2 6 | . . 4 |
| . . . | 7 9 . | 5 . . |
| . . . | . . . | 9 1 . |
+-------+-------+-------+
| . 8 . | 1 . . | . . . |
| 2 3 6 | . . . | 1 8 5 |
| . . . | . . 3 | . 7 . |
+-------+-------+-------+
| . 4 7 | . . . | . . . |
| . . 3 | . 7 8 | . . . |
| 5 . . | 6 3 . | . . . |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

It outputs grids such as this one, which is obviously not valid:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 4 9 | 3 2 6 | 7 3 4 |
| 3 2 4 | 7 9 1 | 5 1 8 |
| 3 7 5 | 3 2 4 | 9 1 2 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 7 8 6 | 1 1 4 | 3 2 5 |
| 2 3 6 | 9 4 7 | 1 8 5 |
| 4 1 7 | 2 3 3 | 6 7 4 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 2 4 7 | 1 1 3 | 5 4 6 |
| 1 3 3 | 4 7 8 | 2 5 1 |
| 5 5 4 | 6 3 2 | 1 3 7 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I really cannot understand why it allows such grids to pass the is_valid test, especially considering that when I manually input the grid above, it doesn't pass the test :

```
>>> s
+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 4 9 | 3 2 6 | 7 3 4 |
| 3 2 4 | 7 9 1 | 5 1 8 |
| 3 7 5 | 3 2 4 | 9 1 2 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 7 8 6 | 1 1 4 | 3 2 5 |
| 2 3 6 | 9 4 7 | 1 8 5 |
| 4 1 7 | 2 3 3 | 6 7 4 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 2 4 7 | 1 1 3 | 5 4 6 |
| 1 3 3 | 4 7 8 | 2 5 1 |
| 5 5 4 | 6 3 2 | 1 3 7 |
+-------+-------+-------+
>>> s.is_valid()
False
```

Can anyone see an error in my code that I haven't noticed? I'm sorry I'm not really being specific but I tried looking through every piece of my code and can't seem to find anything.

For @AnandSKatum :

```
    26  4
   79 5
      91
 8 1
236   185
     3 7
 47
  3 78
5  63
```

Comment: that is alot of code ... I think you can do much better

Comment: Can you add an example of your input file?

Answer (score 0):

here is a better implementation that I wrote for you

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from itertools import chain
import numpy
def block_view(A, block= (3, 3)):
    """Provide a 2D block view to 2D array. No error checking made.
    Therefore meaningful (as implemented) only for blocks strictly
    compatible with the shape of A."""
    # simple shape and strides computations may seem at first strange
    # unless one is able to recognize the 'tuple additions' involved ;-)
    shape= (A.shape[0]/ block[0], A.shape[1]/ block[1])+ block
    strides= (block[0]* A.strides[0], block[1]* A.strides[1])+ A.strides
    return chain.from_iterable(as_strided(A, shape= shape, strides= strides))

def check_board(a):
    """
    a is a 2d 9x9 numpy array, 0 represents None
    """
    for row,col,section in zip(a,a.T,block_view(a,(3,3))):
        s = list(chain.from_iterable(section))
        if any(sum(set(x)) != sum(x) for x in [row,col,s]):
            return False
    return True

a = numpy.array(
    [
        [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
        [2,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [3,6,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [5,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [6,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ]
)

print check_board(a)
```